# Wilson's theorem for a quotient of factorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the least nonnegative residue modulo 11 of $31!\over22!$.

I reduced $31!\over22!$ into $(31)(30)\dots(23)$. Then I tried to group factors of those numbers so that I could get $10!$ so I could apply Wilson's theorem, but I get stuck because I'm missing a last factor of 2. Is there another way to do this question?

Answer (score 1):

$(23\cdot\ldots\cdot31)\bmod{11}=$

$((23\bmod{11})\cdot\ldots\cdot(31\bmod{11}))\bmod{11}=$

$(1\cdot\ldots\cdot9)\bmod{11}=$

$9!\bmod{11}=$

$1$

Comment: Really not sure why I didn't think of this...was probably too focused on Wilson's theorem since that's the section of the book this question is in. Thanks!

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN: You're welcome :)